# ZF2 Doctrine ORM console application - error with execution as phar archive

Tags: orm, console, doctrine, zend-framework2, phar

I wrote simply ZF2 console based application. There is source: https://github.com/vagovszky/console. App is designed for import courses from XML into database. Everything works fine until app is packed into phar.

If I pack this application into phar archive (as described in README.md) and execute it, error occured:

Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException Class "Database\Entity\Ligues" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

I do not know how fix this issue, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DCOM-204): Doctrine's [AnnotationReader](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/) isn't able to read annotations from classes within a PHAR package.